# For GPS point data using android, default camera app or other software?

Tags: gps, android

I'm curious to know about your experience using the default android camera app for geotagging photos vs other apps.

I am going to trial a few different of these apps over the next month or so on different platfirms and I will share a report afterwards however I'm curious to know if anyone has any experience using the default camera app for point mapping and why you might recommend other apps. Do they have the advantage of increased spatial accuracy?

Comment: I am not sure what you exactly want to do but have a look at the following:  http://fulcrumapp.com/                             The app is multi platform and uses GPS and Photos with a editable layout for your notes in the field. You can then export all this data to use in your GIS software.

Answer (score 1):

The application should have zero impact on the accuracy of the GPS point data collected. It's entirely dependent on the hardware, as all the apps will tie into the hardware's GPS reporting. The only way the app will have any sort of impact is if it allows for or incorporates averaging readings over time. Most of the other advanced error correction for GPS signals aren't available to the type of receiver in a phone/tablet. A dedicated data collector should have a much more significant impact to accuracy than which app is being used on a phone.